# How to add parameters to an autogenerated Python Selenium script

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest

I'm new to Selenium and am trying to understand how to pass parameters to a selenium script.

Normally if I call a python script with a parameter like this
**python myprogram.py myparameter**
from the command line, I can lookup the parameter in
    sys.argv[1]
(assuming that I import sys)

An autogenerated selenium script looks like this:
(I already tried to add sys.argv[1] to it)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re
import sys


class ParaN(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):

        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.google.de/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_para(self):

        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "?q=" + sys.argv[1])
        print(driver.current_url )




    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException, e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

This example is supposed to call google with a parameter as a search term.

But unittest.main() doesn't accept parameters and I don't understand what happens when unittest.main() runs, yet.

What's the best approach to add parameters to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`unittest.main()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.main) parses everything you pass on a command-line:

> A command-line program that loads a set of tests from module and runs
>   them; this is primarily for making test modules conveniently
>   executable.

One alternative would be to use a `TestLoader` instead. Replace:

```
unittest.main()
```

with:

```
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(ParaN)
runner.run(suite)
```